# Azure-k8s: Not able to delete Load Balancer service?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

I have deleted my namespace. I check all the resources(i.e. pods,pvc,deployments,svc) are also deleted, however there is a loadbalancer services still under the deleted namespace.
please find the details below :

```
kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   29d
kube-node-lease   Active   29d
kube-public       Active   29d
kube-system       Active   29d
kured             Active   28d
linkerd           Active   24d

kubectl get svc -n z2a-prod
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
abcd-k8s-xyz   LoadBalancer   10.0.16.244   10.0.0.168    9084:32747/TCP,9884:30595/TCP   2d22h
```

I did describe of loadbalancer service, found it is internal.

```
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/**azure-load-balancer-internal**: true
S
```

I tried to remove the finalizer from the loadbalancer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-02T17:23:06Z"
  deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  deletionTimestamp: "2021-02-03T21:53:33Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/**load-balancer-cleanup**
```

and tried to save it. That doesnt work for me.

```
kubectl edit svc abcd-k8s-xyz -n z2a-prod
error: services "abcd-k8s-xyz" could not be found on the server
The edits you made on deleted resources have been saved to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-iizs9.yaml"
```

After above I tried to apply using the same tmp file, that also didnt work for me.

```
    kubectl apply -f /tmp/kubectl-edit-iizs9.yaml
    Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
    Error from server (NotFound): error when applying patch:
for: "/tmp/kubectl-edit-iizs9.yaml": namespaces "z2a-prod" not found
```

Please suggest what it going on here, why I am not able to delete this load balancer.

Comment: This Load Balancer service is linked to PLS and PE. So people who have linked the same way as I did, they need to remove PE first before deleting Load Balancer.
.
For the case in which Load Balancer is not linked with PLS, then edit the Load Balancer and remove the finalizer component and restart the Load Balancer service again.