# "ingress-nginx-controller" service is still not removed after uninstalling chart

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I uninstalled nginx-ingress from my AKS cluster and almost all the resources got deleted my main service which is a type of LoadBalancer is still there I tried deleting manually by using the delete command but still, it's not deleting. I don't know what is the issue please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it keeping into the pending state or not getting removed .

Comment: try `kubectl describe svc <service-name>`

Comment: It's not in pending state and IPs attached to that service is still there.

Comment: try with force...

Comment: Tried force no luck

Answer (score 2):

It may happen due to `service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup` finalizer.

Check [Azure-k8s: Not able to delete Load Balancer service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067108/azure-k8s-not-able-to-delete-load-balancer-service), it can happen LB type service stuck in such way.

I would suggest you open service by running `kubectl edit svc service_name`,   remove below part and saving it again.

```
 finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
```

If that doesnt help please provide in your question detailed verbose deletion output + `kubectl describe svc <service-name>`, as was mentioned before

Comment: It's not the good practice to remove finalizers

Answer (score 1):

(This won't fit in a comment/benefits from formatting)

@Ashis @Vit is correct, but I'll add some clarification around what finalizers are for and why they sometimes need to be patched.

Also in terms of "It's not the good practice to remove finalizers" It's more accurate to say as a general rule of thumb you shouldn't do it. But it's important to know why you shouldn't do it, as that allows you to understand the exception to the rule / when it's fine to go against the rule of thumb.

**Note: This is such a case, here's why**

- Both of the following are true rule of thumb statements:
- Normally you shouldn't have to touch finalizers.
- Normally resources shouldn't be stuck in a deletion state for over 1 hour / never transition to deleted even if you wait 24 hours.
- When you're not in a normal circumstance, it's fine to go against the rule of thumb.

**What's the purpose of finalizers?**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/finalizers/

- Finalizers are responsible for garbage collection / auto deletion of auto provisioned resources.
- If creating a service.yaml can spawn a CSP LB (cloud service provider load balancer)
- Then deleting a service.yaml should delete the CSP LB that was spawned, to prevent orphaned resources from existing/costing money.

**Why can a resource get stuck in an undeletable state?**

- Finalizers are the implementation detail that helps garbage collection of those resources, but the finalizer logic can and will occasionally get stuck in an inconsistent state that requires resolution via manual intervention.
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39420#issuecomment-546781470
  mentions there's a few race condition type bugs that can leave a service stuck in deleting. / put service controller in a confused state. (like a delete and update operation occur at same time) or delete can't succeed because already deleted. And a finalizer never gets updated/removed due to stuck inconsistent state due to race condition bug.
- These race condition bugs (that are inconsistently reproducible, semi-rare, yet somewhat common) occur across OpenShift, GKE, Azure, EKS, and DIY Kubernetes. They can happen with Ingress (mostly on GKE), Services, Namespaces, pvcs, and other objects.
- BTW this trick to fix the inconsistent state of the finalizer even shows up in official CSP docs, like GCP, and Googlers invented Kubernetes.
  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#namespace_stuck_in_terminating_state

**How to fix:**
Read https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/kubectl-delete-stuck-what-to-do/
Here's a summary of what it says

- Start by following the rule of thumb of not deleting a finalier/give time for garbage collection, but after waiting 1 hour consider forceful measures.
- If you're really curious check logs of kube-controller-manager (or other controller like in the case of aws-load-balancer-controller (kube add-on for clusters running on AWS), or a storage class controller add-on (for on premises kubernetes that use DIY storage classes). (These might tell you why the finalizer is stuck.)
- If you understand the external resource that would have been created / that the finalizer is intended to clean up, and you're willing to check if it already got deleted or manually clean it up, then you should be safe to patch the finalizer to null (clearing the inconsistent state), and then delete the object.
- To fix resources stuck in terminating longer than 1h:

  - `kubectl patch (service|ingress|pvc|etc) (name-of-resource) -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge`
- To fix namespaces stuck in terminating logner than 1h:

  - The following works with linux/mac/Win11 WSL2's bash, but assumes jq (json query) is installed
  - `export NS=istio`
  - `kubectl get ns $NS -o json | jq '.spec.finalizers=[]' | kubectl replace --raw /api/v1/namespaces/$NS/finalize -f -`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same. Also if you run this command,
$ kubectl get validatingwebhookconfigurations
try delete them with:

$ kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfigurations

$ kubectl get ingressclass --all-namespaces

$ kubectl delete ingressclass